# Python: Sharing attribute between classes and subclasses

Tags: python, class, attributes, subclass

I have a class A and a subclass B. There is a function in A that, when executed, creates a new attribute of A, and the same attribute is needed for some methods in B. I wanted to know, is there some way to make it so that, if I already have A.attribute, B.attribute exists as well without need to execute the code to add attribute to B?

Comment: It's not clear how (or if) what you're asking for is different from how inheritance already behaves by default.

Comment: Instance attributes belong to instances; it doesn't matter if the attribute on an instance of `B` is created by a method defined in `A` or a method defined in `B`; it's still part of the instance.

Answer (score 0):

This is already how Python handles inheritance:

```
class Parent:
    @classmethod
    def make_attr(cls):
        setattr(cls, 'new_attr', 'some value')

class Child(Parent):
    pass

p = Parent()
c = Child()

p.make_attr()

print(c.new_attr)
```

Personally, I would prefer composition over inheritance for something like this.